# MacOS MeshLab 2020.12 Align Tool

Tags: macos, meshlab

I am a regular, but infrequent user of MeshLab in teaching.  One task I want to do is align a set of imported point clouds (ply files from Capture on an iPhone).  I downloaded MeshLab 2020.12 for MacOS, but I do not see the align tool.  I saw a post that had the same observation.  If someone can tell me if I am missing something, or if something has changed between versions, I would be grateful.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Align tool is broken at least since meshlab 2020.09 and was disabled in version 2020.12.

The developpers are aware and currently trying to solve the problem.

https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/802#issuecomment-737227381